# replacing/deleting substring from a string

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace

I have a function in which I want to delete parts of string from a string.

I want to delete the following substrings `http://` `ftp://` `www.` `www2.` which may be put inf front of a domain name.

Here's the code, but it's not working and I'm probably missing something very obvious.

```
    private function GetValidDomainName($domain)
{
    if(strpos($domain, 'http://'))
    {
        $this->domain = str_replace("http://", "", $domain);
    }
    if(strpos($domain, 'ftp://'))
    {
        $this->domain = str_replace("ftp://", "", $domain);
    }
    if(strpos($domain, 'www.'))
    {
        $this->domain = str_replace("www.", "", $domain);
    }
    if(strpos($domain, 'www2.'))
    {
        $this->domain = str_replace("www2.", "", $domain);
    }

    $dot = strpos($domain, '.'); 
    $this->domain = substr($domain, 0, $dot);
    $this->tld = substr($domain, $dot+1);
}
```

This is a first function which im using in the WHOIS check of the domain availability, I have function that will chech the available characters and allowed domain name lenghts etc later, they all work and the check itself works perfectly fine, but just this function is not doing what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theory:**

You need to check with the [strict comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
if(strpos($domain, 'http://') === 0)
```

... and so on.

That's because [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/strpos) will return either the (first) postion of the occurrence in string or `FALSE` if the sub string wasn't found.

In your case I expect the method will return either `0` meaning the sub string was found at the beginning or `FALSE` if it was not found. Unless you are using the strict comparison operator both will be evaluated to `FALSE` in PHP.

**Praxis:**

You don't need the `strpos()` check at all because `str_replace()` will only work if there is something to replace. You can just use this:

```
$this->domain = str_replace(array(
    'http://', 'ftp://', 'www1', 'www2'
), '', $domain);
```

However this works only unless you can make sure that the urls will not contain `http://` (or one of the others) multiple times. Meaning the following url would break:

```
http://test.server.org/redirect?url=http://server.org
```

To get it stable I would use `preg_replace()`:

```
$pattern = '~^((http://|ftp://~|www1\.|www2\.))~'
$this->domain = preg_replace($pattern, '', $domain);
```

The pattern above will remove the sub strings only if they appear at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The first one nearly works, but for some reasons it doesn't remove the dot from 'www.' or 'www2.', however it doesn't work with http:// and ftp:// at all. The preg_replace gives me the following error `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '|'`.

Comment: Check my update, I missed some `()`.. Should work now. Need to leave urgently from keyboard. can help later maybe.

Comment: Yup, nearly there, I got this working now with the first method. It doesn't work in case of `http://www.` but even if i create the `else if` for it, it still doesn't seems to work. The `pattern` still gives me the worning and allows for `www.` and `www2.`. It's important that those gets deleted.